# Does the css rule font-family overwrite all of the inherited fonts or just adds more options?

Tags: css

I have this problem:

```
body{
  font-family: 'MyFontFace-font', 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, etc.
}

H1 {
 font-family: 'MyFontFace-font2'
}
```

And my question is: If the second font ('MyFontFace-font2') is not loaded, will H1 have the font inherited from body, or from default of browser?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. And checking it by yourself would have been faster than asking us and waiting for an answer :)

Comment: No, actually. Not on all browsers. Webkit does this, but not Gecko.

Comment: So, it is necessary use always full font-family format for better fallback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default fallback fonts of the browser will be applied, and any setting on `body` is ignored.

When you assign a value to a property of an element, like `font-family` to `h1` here, then inheritance will never apply to that property on that element (except, trivially, if you assign the value `inherit` and the browser supports that). This is not changed by casual things like the value specifying a nonexistent font.

I also tested this with the following simpler document (on a system that has no font named `MyFontFace-font2` but has a font named `Tahoma`):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test5</title>
<style>
body{
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
H1 {
  font-family: 'MyFontFace-font2'
}
</style>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

In Chrome, Firefox, IE the result is that the browser’s default font is used, not Tahoma. This is the expected result, by the specifications.

If the rule on `H1` is omitted, then Tahoma is used, due to inheritance – *then* the `h1` element will inherit the `font-family` property from its parent.